# Prohibit CSS files in specific pages

Tags: 7, theming

I am using a custom theme in Drupal and the jquery and bootstrap version in pretty outdated. Old pages in are in that version but I want to design few new pages where I want to include the latest version of bootstrap and jQuery. Now whenever I design a new page, Drupal itself adds certain wrappers to it and includes the previous bootstrap, jQuery version in the aggregate JavaScript file. I just want it to be plain HTML and not include any other CSS/JavaScript files, or make any other modification.

I have added CSS and JavaScript files in link and script tags. Few elements also have inline CSS styles. I just want it to render as simple HTML page.

Currently this is my theme.inc file.

```
 foreach ($stylesheets as $stylesheet) {
   drupal_add_css($stylesheet, array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'every_page' => TRUE, 'media' => $media));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [hook_js_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7.x) and [hook_css_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7.x). Using these hooks you can remove any CSS and/or JS file.